# Is it possible to save the returned value of a function for the next time it is called?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, save

I'm writing a function that iteratively calculates an integral and for the next estimate I need the previous result.

I'm using an auxiliary variable to store the previous result and it works, but is it possible to do that inside the own function (something similar to SAVE declared variables in fortran)?

Comment: Where's the code?

Comment: No, there isn't anything like that in Python. Python and Fortran are pretty different languages. In python, you would normally just do what you are doing already, or use something like a class (or even a function closure). But honestly, what you have sounds good and normal

Comment: I've never heard of a language other than Fortran doing this - and today was the first I heard of Fortran doing it.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel, pretty much the same as declaring a vrbl `static` in the body of a C function.  For example, `static int count = 0;` at the top of a function, `++count` in the body, and then you have a persistent count of the number of times the function has been called.

Comment: *Ah*. Yes, that makes sense, thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nothing automagic, but functions in Python can have attributes.  So, e.g., this works:

```
>>> def f(n):
...     result = n+1
...     f.last = result
...     return result
>>> f(6)
7
>>> f.last
7
```

Nothing magic about the name `last` there - just an arbitrary identifier I made up.  Of course you can bind that attribute outside the function body too:

```
>>> f.last = 12
>>> f.last
12
```

### Magic

If you do a lot of this (which I wouldn't really recommend), it's possible to automate it with a bit of code, via writing a "decorator" you can apply to functions to alter their behavior. This *is* quite magical:

```
# Decorator to change a function to save its last return value
# in attribute `last`.
from functools import wraps
def addlast(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def g(*args, **kw):
        g.last = f(*args, **kw)
        return g.last
    g.last = None
    return g
```

Given that, you can put "@addlast" right before a function definition to alter its behavior, without changing the function itself:

```
@addlast
def f(i, j):
    return i + j

print(f.last)
print(f(3, 9))
print(f.last)
```

which displays:

```
None
12
12
```